# Get enabled content types machine name

Tags: 8, group

I'm trying to get the enabled content type machine names for a given group.

I wrote the following code, but to get the machine name I should cut the strings to *group_node:*.

```
    /** @var \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupType $group */
    $group = GroupType::load($groupKey);
    $plugins = $group->getInstalledContentPlugins();
    foreach ($plugins->getConfiguration() as $key => $plugin) {
      // Cut key here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know how I missed this.

```
/** @var \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupType $group */
$group = GroupType::load($groupKey);
$plugins = $group->getInstalledContentPlugins();
foreach ($plugins as $key => $plugin) {
  $bundle = $plugin->getEntityBundle();
}
```